# Do boxing or go boxing?

Tags: verbs

Looking at https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-do-or-go-boxing.1457472/ and http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/vocabulary-verbs-used-to-talk-about-sports-play-do-go/ I found that we should say: "I box". Also it may depend on context.

There is a list of exceptions:

- boxing
- fencing
- weight training

How should we say about boxing in different contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean different things, although you will see them used interchangeably because the *outcome* is the same.

- *Doing* something means taking part in it.
- *Going* something means going somewhere to do it. For example, "going swimming" means going to the pool to swim.

With your example of boxing, "going boxing" sounds more casual, and certainly doesn't sound like you're doing it at a professional level. It sounds like you are going to training sessions. *Doing* something doesn't necessarily mean professionally, but it sounds like you must already have the skills in order to do it.

Maybe you don't even need to use either. You could just say "I box".

Comment: The second link which the OP provides says 'Do not use another verb with _boxing, fencing_ or _weight training_', and recommends 'I box'. Personally, I don't know enough about these sports to know how people normally talk about them.

Comment: Astralbee and @KateBunting, thank you very much! I wanted to listen to opinions of native speakers. Well, you answered the question.